# Array mapping with JOLT

Tags: jolt

First time JOLT user trying to restructure an array into a similar multi-level array. stackoverflow is asking for less code and more words, so I hope this extra sentence covers that.

Input JSON

```
  {
    "studentIdentifier": "453089029",
    "studentRegistrationNumber": "753082022",
    "parentIdentifier": "1001142760",
    "parentFamilyName": "lastname1001142760",
    "relationshipIdentifier": "1001142762",
    "relationshipToStudent": "Mother"
  },
  {
    "studentIdentifier": "453089193",
    "studentRegistrationNumber": "753082123",
    "parentIdentifier": "1001142760",
    "parentFamilyName": "lastname1001142760",
    "relationshipIdentifier": "1001159585",
    "relationshipToStudent": "Mother"
  }
]
```

Desired JSON output

```
{
  "carer" : {
    "relationships" : [ {
      "relationshipIdentifier" : "1001142762",
      "relationshipToStudent" : "Mother",
      "student" : {
        "studentIdentifier" : "453089029",
        "studentRegistrationNumber" : "753082022"
      }
    }, {
      "relationshipIdentifier" : "1001159585",
      "relationshipToStudent" : "Mother",
      "student" : {
        "studentIdentifier" : "453089193",
        "studentRegistrationNumber" : "753082123"
      }
    } ],
    "parentIdentifier" : "1001142760",
    "parentFamilyName" : "lastname1001142760"
  }
}
```

JOLT spec so far

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "@": "carer.relationships[].student",
        "parent*": "carer.&"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "cardinality",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "parent*": "ONE"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "remove",
    "spec": {
      "carer": {
        "relationships": {
          "*": {
            "student": {
              "parent*": "",
              "relationship*": ""
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Currently getting this result

```
{
  "carer" : {
    "relationships" : [ {
      "student" : {
        "studentIdentifier" : "453089029",
        "studentRegistrationNumber" : "753082022"
      }
    }, {
      "student" : {
        "studentIdentifier" : "453089193",
        "studentRegistrationNumber" : "753082123"
      }
    } ],
    "parentIdentifier" : "1001142760",
    "parentFamilyName" : "lastname1001142760"
  }
}
```

How to map the missing relationship* fields at the right level or is there a better approach?

Answer (score 0):

Spec:

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": "&",
        "student*": "carer.relationships[&1].student.&",
        "relationship*": "carer.relationships[&1].&"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "cardinality",
    "spec": {
      "parent*": "ONE"
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my answer below

```
[
  {
"operation": "shift",
"spec": {
  "*": {
    "relationshipIdentifier": "carer.relationships.[&1].relationshipIdentifier",
    "relationshipToStudent": "carer.relationships.[&1].relationshipToStudent",
    "studentIdentifier": "carer.relationships.[&1].student.studentIdentifier",
    "studentRegistrationNumber": "carer.relationships.[&1].student.studentRegistrationNumber",
    "parentIdentifier": "carer.parentIdentifier",
    "parentFamilyName": "carer.parentFamilyName"
  }
}
 },
  {
    "operation": "cardinality",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "parentIdentifier": "ONE",
        "parentFamilyName": "ONE"
  }
}
}
]
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).